# How delete/remove task from ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I want to remove the task definition from the service. How can I do that?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Actually we can not remove the task definition from service because task definition is like the heart of the service and based on task definition service will start the tasks for the service. Its basically blue print for the task which will eventually make your complete service.

But we can always update the service [1] with any other task definition or with any new version of same task definition.

How to delete/remove task from ECS service?
If we will click on any task (on screenshot in task section) it will redirect you to that specific task page and on right side top corner we will see the option which will help to stop the task.

But eventually ECS service will start new task to maintain the desired count and if you dont want that best way to stop all task for service is update the service [1] and set desired count to "0".

[1] Updating a Service - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/update-service.html